# How can I attach a kick down door stop to a hollow metal door?

Tags: doors, metal

I have a hollow-core metal door out to my car port, and it gets a lot of traffic.  I'd like to add a kick-down door stop to the door.  I think one option is to drill pilot holes and use self-tapping screws to secure the stop to the front part of the door.  But I'm worried that this will bend the door's sheet metal.  Should I instead drill all the way through the door and bolt the door stop to a plate on the other side?  If so, is there any way to make that look nice?

Comment: You're going to install it close to the corner of the door right?  You should have more strength there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the plate with spacers combined with internal threads you should be able to arrange that the screws cause a clamping on one surface and just a bit of compression on the whole thickness.

Comment: What's a spacer?

Comment: @Alex think of a washer but thicker as necessary.